# library not found when starting youbot_driver_ros_interface

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a youbot running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and ROS Hydro. I installed the `ros-hydro-youbot-driver` and `ros-hydro-youbot-driver-ros-interface packages`. When I try to start the ros driver using `roslaunch youbot_driver_ros_interface youbot_driver.launch` I get the following error message which relates to [[1]](http://answers.ros.org/question/65151/libtfso-cannot-open-shared-object-file/)

```
    core service [/rosout] found
    /opt/ros/hydro/lib/youbot_driver_ros_interface/youbot_driver_ros_interface: error while loading shared libraries: process[youbot_driver-1]: started with pid [3765]
    libtf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    [youbot_driver-1] process has died [pid 3765, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/youbot_driver_ros_interface/youbot_driver_ros_interface base/joint_states:=joint_states arm_1/joint_states:=joint_states __name:=youbot_driver __log:=/home/youbot/.ros/log/cb1447ea-9df2-11e3-9357-0022697f602c/youbot_driver-1.log].
    log file: /home/youbot/.ros/log/cb1447ea-9df2-11e3-9357-0022697f602c/youbot_driver-1*.log
    all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
    shutting down processing monitor...
    ... shutting down processing monitor complete
    done
```

Note that before I got this error message I also had a different problem with the package: I had to set the ethernet capabilites like described in the building from source section (2.2.2) here: [[2]](http://wiki.ros.org/youbot_driver) This might be a bug or could be related to this error.

After executing `ldconfig /opt/ros/hydro/lib` I now get the following error message:

```
[ INFO] [1393319937.340360990]: Configuration file path: /opt/ros/hydro/share/youbot_driver/config
[ INFO] [1393319937.364843922]: Initializing EtherCAT on eth0 with communication thread
[FATAL] [1393319937.388841667]: No EtherCAT slaves found!
[ERROR] [1393319937.389182353]: Base "youbot-base" could not be initialized.
[ INFO] [1393319937.389486163]: Configuration file path: /opt/ros/hydro/share/youbot_driver/config
[FATAL] [1393319937.392086845]: No socket connection on eth0
Excecute as root
[ERROR] [1393319937.392452185]: Arm "youbot-manipulator" could not be initialized.
[ INFO] [1393319937.392667785]: System has 0 initialized arm(s).
[ WARN] [1393319937.393588013]: ../config/youbot-ethercat.cfg file not found
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'youbot::FileNotFoundException'
  what():  ../config/youbot-ethercat.cfg file not found
[youbot_driver-1] process has died [pid 5955, exit code
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132836/library-not-found-when-starting-youbot_driver_ros_interface/) by [Jabro](https://answers.ros.org/users/9246/jabro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jabro](https://answers.ros.org/users/9246/jabro/) on 2014-02-24**:
adding export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libtf.so"
to zshrc/bashrc also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the debian package for the youbot-driver-ros-interface did not work yet because of missing run time dependencies. WIth the next ROS debian update cycle hopefully this should be fixed.

So far it is recommended to compile it yourself, as described [here](http://www.youbot-store.com/youbot-developers/software/ros/ros-hydro-wrapper-for-kuka-youbot-api?c=24)

The second problem with the error "No socket connection on eth0" is usually due to

- forgot "setcap" command for the youbot_driver_ros_interface executable
- another port than eth0 is connected (see [here](http://www.youbot-store.com/wiki/index.php?title=No_EtherCAT_Slaves_found))
- hardware issue with cabling, emergency stop etc.

If you did the first thing and still does not work, you might want to send a message to hotline@youbot-store.com as it is probably not related to ROS anymore.

Hi, the debian package for the youbot-driver-ros-interface did not work yet because of missing run time dependencies. WIth the next ROS debian update cycle hopefully this should be fixed.

So far it is recommended to compile it yourself, as described [here](http://www.youbot-store.com/youbot-developers/software/ros/ros-hydro-wrapper-for-kuka-youbot-api?c=24)

The second problem with the error "No socket connection on eth0" is usually due to

- forgot "setcap" command for the youbot_driver_ros_interface executable
- another port than eth0 is connected (see [here](http://www.youbot-store.com/wiki/index.php?title=No_EtherCAT_Slaves_found))
- hardware issue with cabling, emergency stop etc.

If you did the first thing and still does not work, you might want to send a message to hotline@youbot-store.com as it is probably not related to ROS anymore.

---

Originally posted by [praman2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/12421/praman2s/) with karma: 31 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [praman2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/12421/praman2s/) on 2014-02-25**:
We are not able to edit the answer, same answer posted twice. Solution offered by Walter Nowak.